# Can't merge 2 branches - already up to date

Tags: git

I have 2 branches that are different:

```
git diff master..my-branch2
```

However, when I do this when I'm in the branch master:

```
git merge my-branch2
```

I get this:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Why is that and how do I merge them?

UPDATE:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git branch --contains master
* master

$ git branch --contains my-branch2
* master
my-branch2
my-branch3
```

Comment: The most likely explanation is that `my-branch2`'s tip is a parent of `master`'s tip, in which case Git has nothing to merge. What does `git branch --contains master` tell you? Is `my-branch2` listed in the output?

Comment: @Jubobs, `$ git branch --contains master` shows only master, although I have a number of other branches.

Comment: What about `git branch --contains branch2`?

Comment: I would rather recommend checking the status with `git log --oneline --graph --decorate master branch2` for the clarity

Comment: Well, your branch is contained in `master`, so there's nothing to merge.  Do you want to merge `master` into `my-branch2` instead?  This will result in a fast forward unless you specify `-no-ff`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, and the result code will be the same when I merge them?

Comment: @SvenMarnach, meaning it's no difference wether I merge branch1 into branch2 or branch2 into branch1?

Comment: There is a difference.  `git merge other-branch` will merge `other-branch` into the current one, i.e. include all changes that are in `other-branch` but not in the current one, and update only the crurrent branch.

Comment: @Trengot Ah yes, I got it backwards. `git branch --contains my-branch2` is the right command, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this:

```
$ git branch --contains my-branch2
* master
my-branch2
my-branch3
```

we see that the `my-branch2` has already been merged to master. It lags behind, hence the difference, but there is nothing left to merge to master hence the message you see:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Which means you don't have to do anything to merge your changes.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Yes, they are different.  But one contains already all the changes of the other, hence there is nothing to merge.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp you may use `git log my-branch2 --not master`. If you see any revision there - there is something left for merge. If not - you don't need to merge to master.

Answer (score 3):

Merging is meant to resolve a situation where two branches have diverged:

```
A - B - C   <-- master
 \
  D - E     <-- my-branch2
```

Merging in this situation means to create a new commit that contains all the changes introduced by `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` on top of `A`.

If one of the branches is already contained in the other one -- in your situation

```
A - B - C   <-- master
^
my-branch2
```

there is nothing to do if you want to merge the branch `my-branch2` into `master` -- all the changes are already contained in `master`.  On the other hand, `my-branch2` does not contain all changes in `master`, but merging `master` into `my-branch2` can be trivially done by moving `my-branch2` forward to `master`.  This is called a fast forward.